# Razor Pages and Razor Views

Tags: reactjs, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Is it a good idea to mix `Razor Pages` with `Razor Views` in the same ASP.NET Core 2.0 app?

If I understand it correctly, the benefit of using `Razor Pages` is that they don't need controller actions. In my app, I have some pages that simply return a React app. I feel `Razor Pages` are perfect for this because all I need in the page is just a link to the `bundle.js` file.

Having said that, I do have a few pages where I need a controller and send a view model.

So, is it a good idea to have both pages and views or should I stick to one and not mix it together?

Comment: You can absolutely mix them. If that’s a good idea depends on you but the way you describe your app, it sounds like having both makes sense. So just choose whatever makes sense to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read recently about Razor Pages in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio) and Rick Anderson(member of ASP.Core team) said here that:

> You can mix controllers, views and Razor Pages. RP are unit testable
>   (using code-behind). It's a good question. See
>   https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/494#issuecomment-232534742 for
>   motivation.

So you can mix. The only tiny issue, in my opinion, that I read from the docs that:

> Note: The layout is in the Pages folder. Pages look for other views
>   (layouts, templates, partials) hierarchically, starting in the same
>   folder as the current page. This means that a layout in the Pages
>   folder can be used from any Razor page under the Pages folder.

Which means that you cannot use the same layouts, templates, partials both for Razor Page and View out of the box, without modifying ASP conventions or writing some custom solution to use the same layouts, templates, partials both for Razor Page and View. Otherwise mix them looks perfectly fine.

Comment: You can simply specify the full path to these items if  you want to share a layout between Razor Pages and Razor Views. This better might be better than automatically searching both the Views hierarchy and the Pages hierarchy. After all, sometimes you might not want to share them and if it's automatic you are kind of stuck.